# Requesting guidance on slickgrid implementation for ASP.Net 3.5 web forms app

Tags: slickgrid

I'm looking for some guidance on how to implement the slickgrid in an ASP.net web application.  The application queries a sql server 2005 database and currently uses gridviews to display the data.  My goal is to eliminate the use of gridviews and replace them with the slickgrid.  My code is below and I'm not sure how or where to start.

In my Dashboard.aspx.cs file (below) you will see that I bind my data to gridviews.  How do I replace the databinding to utilize the slickgrid?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Dashboard.aspx page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    <table style="width: 100%; table-layout: auto; border-top-style: none; border-right-style: none; border-left-style: none; border-collapse: collapse; border-bottom-style: none;">
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="8" align="center" valign="top">
                <asp:Button ID="btnRefresh" runat="server" OnClick="btnRefresh_Click" Text="Refresh"
                    Width="100px" />
                    <br />
                <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" PostBackUrl="~/InterfaceListing.aspx" Text="Interface List"
                    Width="100px" />
            </td>
            <td style="color: #990000; font-family: Tahoma; height: 1px; text-align: left; width: 124px;">
                &nbsp;</td>
            <td style="width: 19px; height: 1px">
                &nbsp;</td>
            <td style="height: 1px; width: 216px;">
                &nbsp;</td>
            <td style="width: 20%; height: 19px">
                &nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="color: #990000; font-family: Tahoma; height: 1px; text-align: left; width: 124px;">
                <span style="font-size: 11pt; vertical-align: top;">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Last 10 Jobs Executed" Width="307px"></asp:Label></span></td>
            <td style="width: 19px; height: 1px">
            </td>
            <td style="height: 1px; width: 216px;">
                <span style="font-size: 11pt; color: #990000; font-family: Tahoma">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Interface Summary" Width="185px"></asp:Label></span></td>
            <td style="width: 20%; height: 19px">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 124px; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">
                <asp:GridView ID="gvLast10" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4"
                    Font-Names="Tahoma" Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="#333333"
                    GridLines="None" Width="800px" >
                    <RowStyle BackColor="#FFFBD6" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" ForeColor="#333333" />
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="InterfaceName" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="InterfaceName">
                            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                        </asp:BoundField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="TotalTransactionCount" HeaderText="Transaction Count" SortExpression="TotalTransactionCount">
                            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        </asp:BoundField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="ErrorsOccured" HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="ErrorsOccured">
                            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        </asp:BoundField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="RunTime" HeaderText="Duration" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="RunTime">
                            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        </asp:BoundField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Started" HeaderText="Started" SortExpression="DateBegan">
                            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                        </asp:BoundField>
                    </Columns>
                    <FooterStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <PagerStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" ForeColor="#333333" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Navy" />
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#990000" BorderColor="#990000" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px"
                        Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                </asp:GridView>
            </td>
            <td style="vertical-align: top; width: 19px; text-align: left">
            </td>
            <td style="width: 216px; vertical-align: top; text-align: left;">
                <asp:GridView ID="gvPackageCount" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4"
                    ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" Width="195px" Font-Names="Tahoma" Font-Size="8pt">
                    <RowStyle BackColor="#FFFBD6" ForeColor="#333333" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" />
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Status" HeaderText="Status" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Status"
                            Visible="False" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" ReadOnly="True"
                            SortExpression="Description">
                            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                        </asp:BoundField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Count" HeaderText="Count" ReadOnly="True"
                            SortExpression="Count">
                            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        </asp:BoundField>
                    </Columns>
                    <FooterStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <PagerStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" ForeColor="#333333" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Navy" />
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" BorderColor="#990000" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" />
                    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                </asp:GridView>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 20%; height: 19px">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 124px; color: #990000; background-color: white; height: 19px;">
                <span style="font-size: 11pt; font-family: Tahoma">
                    <br />
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Next 10 Jobs Scheduled" Width="236px"></asp:Label></span></td>
            <td style="width: 19px; height: 19px">
            </td>
            <td style="width: 216px; height: 19px;">
                <span style="font-size: 11pt; font-family: Tahoma"></span>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 20%; height: 19px">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 124px; vertical-align: top; height: 147px;">
                <asp:GridView ID="gvNext10" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4"
                    Font-Names="Tahoma" Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="#333333"
                    GridLines="None" Width="800px">
                    <RowStyle BackColor="#FFFBD6" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" ForeColor="#333333" />
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Interfacename" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Interfacename">
                            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                        </asp:BoundField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Next Run" HeaderText="Next Run" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Next Run">
                            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                        </asp:BoundField>
                    </Columns>
                    <FooterStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <PagerStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" ForeColor="#333333" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Navy" />
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#990000" BorderColor="#990000" BorderWidth="1px" Font-Bold="True"
                        ForeColor="White" />
                    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                </asp:GridView>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 19px; height: 147px">
            </td>
            <td style="width: 216px; height: 147px; vertical-align: bottom; text-align: center;">
                &nbsp;
                </td>
            <td style="width: 20%; height: 19px">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="vertical-align: top; width: 124px">

            </td>
            <td style="width: 19px">
            </td>
            <td style="width: 216px">
            </td>
            <td style="width: 20%; height: 19px">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="color: #990000; font-family: Tahoma; height: 1px; text-align: left; width: 124px;">
                <span style="font-size: 11pt; vertical-align: top;">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Jobs In Process" 
                    Width="307px"></asp:Label></span></td>
            <td style="width: 19px; height: 1px">
                &nbsp;</td>
            <td style="height: 1px; width: 216px;">
                &nbsp;</td>
            <td style="width: 20%; height: 19px">
                &nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="color: #990000; font-family: Tahoma; height: 1px; text-align: left; width: 124px;">
                <asp:GridView ID="gvInProcess" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4"
                    Font-Names="Tahoma" Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="#333333"
                    GridLines="None" Width="800px" >
                    <RowStyle BackColor="#FFFBD6" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" ForeColor="#333333" />
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="InterfaceName" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="InterfaceName">
                            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                        </asp:BoundField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Started" HeaderText="Started" SortExpression="DateBegan">
                            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                        </asp:BoundField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="RunTime" HeaderText="Duration" 
                            SortExpression="RunTime" ReadOnly="True">
                            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        </asp:BoundField>
                    </Columns>
                    <FooterStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <PagerStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" ForeColor="#333333" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Navy" />
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#990000" BorderColor="#990000" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px"
                        Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                </asp:GridView>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 19px; height: 1px">
                &nbsp;</td>
            <td style="height: 1px; width: 216px;">
                &nbsp;</td>
            <td style="width: 20%; height: 19px">
                &nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    &nbsp;
    <br />
    <br />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Dashboard.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace IntegrationSupport
{
    public partial class Dashboard : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        ClassData cd = new ClassData();

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable dt1 = cd.Dashboard("Summary");
            gvPackageCount.DataSource = dt1;
            gvPackageCount.DataBind();

            DataTable dt2 = cd.Dashboard("Last10");
            gvLast10.DataSource = dt2;
            gvLast10.DataBind();

            DataTable dt3 = cd.Dashboard("Next10");
            gvNext10.DataSource = dt3;
            gvNext10.DataBind();

            DataTable dt4 = cd.Dashboard("InProcess");
            gvInProcess.DataSource = dt4;
            gvInProcess.DataBind();

        }
        protected void btnRefresh_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/Dashboard.aspx");

        }
    }
}
```

ClassData.cs:

```
public DataTable Dashboard(string Section)
        {
            //Get Dashboard Sections...
            string sStoredProc = string.Empty;
            switch (Section)
            {
                case "Summary":
                    sStoredProc = "InterfaceListing_DashboardDataset";
                    break;
                case "Last10":
                    sStoredProc = "InterfaceListing_Dashboard_6Last10Jobs";
                    break;
                case "Next10":
                    sStoredProc = "InterfaceListing_Dashboard_7Next10Jobs";
                    break;
                case "InProcess":
                    sStoredProc = "InterfaceListing_Dashboard_JobsInProcess";
                    break;
                default:
                    sStoredProc = "";
                break;   

            }


            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            Open();
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandText = sStoredProc;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            Ada = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dtInterface = new DataTable();
            Ada.Fill(dtInterface);
            return dtInterface;

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm looking for some guidance on how to implement the slickgrid in an ASP.net web >application. The application queries a sql server 2005 database and currently uses gridviews >to display the data. My goal is to eliminate the use of gridviews and replace them with the >slickgrid. My code is below and I'm not sure how or where to start.

this will help u:
 http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/183301/Real-Time-Stock-Quotes-Stock-Alerts-Indicators-Usi